# Is it possible to find a certain co-prime number in this arithmetic progression?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

Let, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(a_2,\dots,a_{n-1}) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$$\alpha_k = (1+2n + a_2n(n-1) + a_3n(n-1)(n-2) + \dots + a_{n-1}(n(n-1)\dots4*3) ~ ) + kn!, ~ ~  k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
Is it possible to find a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\alpha_k$ is prime? Or a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$\gcd((1+2n + a_2n(n-1) + a_3n(n-1)(n-2) + \dots + a_{n-1}) , kn!) = 1? $$

Comment: "Or a $k \in \mathbb Z$ such that ..."?  But the last equation doesn't involve $k$ at all.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, sorry fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. For example, let $n=7$, and all $a_i=3$. Then
$$\alpha_k= 1+2 \cdot 7 + \mathrm{some \ stuff \ divisible \ by \ } 3 + k \cdot 7!$$
which is obviously a multiple of $3$ for every $k \in \Bbb Z$. In particular it is not prime.

As for the second question, it is equivalent to the first question.
Indeed, fixed two integers $a,b$, there is a prime of the form
$$a+bk$$
if and only if $(a,b)=1$. This is known as Dirichlet theorem.